# Using spread when initializing array in Go

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I have a repeating list of values which I want to re-use when initializing several arrays like that:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var i = []int{1, 2, 3}
    var a = []int{2, i..., 3}
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

This code above gives the following error:

> ./prog.go:9:20: syntax error: unexpected ..., expecting comma or }

I wanted to use the spread `...` operator but this does not seem to be possible while initializing an array.

Am I missing something here or spreading is not allowed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only use `...` with a slice when passing it to a variadic function. See [Spec: Passing arguments to ... parameters](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

So for example you could use it when passing it to [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append):

```
var i = []int{1, 2, 3}
a := append([]int{2}, i...)
a = append(a, 3)
fmt.Println(a)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/rmgkiVBGJLB)):

```
[2 1 2 3 3]
```

Alternatively the above can be written in one line:

```
a := append(append([]int{2}, i...), 3)
```

Do note that this may be compact, it's not necessarily efficient as it may create and copy multiple backing arrays under the hood.

To ensure a single allocation, you could use `make()` with capacity provided, for example:

```
a := make([]int, 0, 2+len(i))
a = append(a, 2)
a = append(a, i...)
a = append(a, 3)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/tCGewcIbtv1).

Yet another solution is to use [`copy()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy) if you have the slice preallocated (either with [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) or using indices in the compositle literal):

```
a := []int{2, 4: 3}
copy(a[1:], i)
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ePPvN6xQSx9). The disadvantage here is that the index (`4: 3`) must be constant and can't be something like `1 + len(i)`. If you'd want to preallocate the slice (e.g. `make([]int, 2+len(i))`), you can't combine that with a composite literal to list elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's a bit more verbose that I'd like it to be but will get the job done.

Comment: @AquilaX Added note about efficiency and some alternative solutions.